# Can't hold my checkbox checked color when goes to one activity to another in android

Tags: android

this is my code

```
ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        // perform logic
                        new LikeTask().execute();
                        ck1.setTag(R.drawable.fill_like);
                        ck1.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.fill_like);
                    } else {
                        // perform logic
                        new UnLikeTask().execute();
                        ck1.setTag(R.drawable.like);
                        ck1.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.like);
                    }

                }

            });
```

Comment: use sharedpreferences.

Comment: From your question, it not clear. better add some images.

Comment: What is can suggest from what I get is that: You should use the savedinstance() and resumeInstance to restore all the state of custom UI.